# Will using Android x affect the compatibility of my app?

Tags: android, flutter, android-support-library, androidx

**Hello ,** I have a simple question ,, if I migrated my Flutter app to Android X , will this effect the minimum android version required to install and run my app ? and how to know the minimum android version required to install my current app in any moment ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can check min version of your app in your app's build.gradle
See picture for more details.
[image]

Edit: if you have created your project recently then you don't have to worry about the minimum version. although migrating does not effect min version.
For more [visit here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: And if you have created your project recently then you don't have to worry about the minimum version. although migrating does not effect min version

Answer (score 1):

No android handles **androidx** in flutter automatically.To know the minimum version of your app,go to apps build.gradle and check the **minsdkversion**.